How to run the PySpark code on wsl visual studio?
I have written a PySpark code on WSL Ubuntu using Visual Studio. Every time I make a change, I have to build the WHL file, upload it to the Databricks cluster, and run the job.
Is there a way to debug the code locally in Visual Studio or any other IDE? When I try to debug the code in Visual Studio, I get a "No module found" error. Can you provide a solution for this?
Is there any approach to debug the code locally and my source is azure event hub, and also I have multiple python files
